# How to delete a Module from the AWS CloudFormation Registry?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I started using [CloudFormation Modules](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/modules.html) in my templates as a way to promote reuse and company best practices. I created a couple of modules as a proof-of-concept, which appeared in the [CloudFormation Registry](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/registry.html) in AWS Console as expected.

The problem I'm having is that I would like to delete these test modules and build the real ones. I can't seem to find a way to do this, or even any documentation stating that it's not possible and why not. Is this possible, if so how?

The steps I ran to create/register the module are described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation-cli/latest/userguide/modules-develop.html):

```
cfn init
cfn submit
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`aws cloudformation deregister-type --arn`

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/deregister-type.html

https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cloudformation-cli/issues/401

Comment: This seems more of a documentation issue than anything. Mentioning `deregister`-type` in the links I provided would fix it. Maybe the command/option names could have been better, but who am I to judge.